# Issue getting the restrictions on a class

Tags: jena

I have a simple ontology designed using Protégé 3.4. I've introduced some "Necessary & Sufficient" conditions, like in the defintion of the Table class:

http://postimage.org/image/f37xliqad/

Forget the two first conditions, the third one is easier to understand :)

The OWL code generated is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:protege="http://protege.stanford.edu/plugins/owl/protege#"
    xmlns:xsp="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/2005/08/07/xsp.owl#"
    xmlns:assert="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/assert.owl#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:sqwrl="http://sqwrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/built-ins/3.4/sqwrl.owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:swrl="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrl#"
    xmlns:swrlb="http://www.w3.org/2003/11/swrlb#"
    xmlns="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1317586695.owl#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:swrla="http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/3.3/swrla.owl#"
  xml:base="http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1317586695.owl">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://swrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/3.3/swrla.owl"/>
    <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://sqwrl.stanford.edu/ontologies/built-ins/3.4/sqwrl.owl"/>
  </owl:Ontology>
```

...

```
  <owl:Class rdf:ID="Table">
    <owl:disjointWith>
      <owl:Class rdf:ID="Chair"/>
    </owl:disjointWith>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:Class>
        <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <rdf:first>
            <owl:Restriction>
              <owl:onProperty>
                <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="has_coarseArea"/>
              </owl:onProperty>
              <owl:someValuesFrom>
                <owl:Class>
                  <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                    <owl:Class rdf:about="#MMAround09"/>
                    <owl:Class rdf:about="#MMAround1"/>
                    <owl:Class rdf:about="#MMAround12"/>
                    <owl:Class rdf:about="#MMAround15"/>
                    <owl:Class rdf:about="#MMAround2"/>
                  </owl:unionOf>
                </owl:Class>
              </owl:someValuesFrom>
            </owl:Restriction>
          </rdf:first>
          <rdf:rest rdf:parseType="Resource">
            <rdf:first>
              <owl:Restriction>
                <owl:someValuesFrom>
                  <owl:Class>
                    <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                      <owl:Class rdf:about="#MMAround07"/>
                      <owl:Class rdf:about="#MMAround08"/>
                    </owl:unionOf>
                  </owl:Class>
                </owl:someValuesFrom>
                <owl:onProperty>
                  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:ID="has_coarseCentroidHeight"/>
                </owl:onProperty>
              </owl:Restriction>
            </rdf:first>
            <rdf:rest>
              <rdf:List>
                <rdf:first>
                  <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:someValuesFrom>
                      <owl:Class rdf:about="#Horizontal"/>
                    </owl:someValuesFrom>
                    <owl:onProperty>
                      <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#has_orientation"/>
                    </owl:onProperty>
                  </owl:Restriction>
                </rdf:first>
                <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
              </rdf:List>
            </rdf:rest>
          </rdf:rest>
        </owl:intersectionOf>
      </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
      <owl:Class rdf:ID="Furniture"/>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
  </owl:Class>
```

If I've understood well, these conditions are interpreted as restrictions, and managed as a super-class of the Table class.

So, if I load my ontology and the class Table with Jena:

```
1. String NS = "http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology1317586695.owl#";
2. OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC);
3. model.read(OWL_FILE_NAME);
4. OntClass Table = model.getOntClass( NS + "Table" );
```

The NS variable has a correct value since the Table OntClass is loaded correctly. Then, while executing the following code, the line the line 10 should be reached, but it's not:

```
5. for (Iterator<OntClass> supers = Table.listSuperClasses(true); supers.hasNext(); ) {
6.            OntClass  superClass = supers.next();
7.           
8.            if (superClass.isRestriction())
9.            {
10.               System.out.println("Restriction found");
11.            }
12. }
```

I've tried with Table.listEquivalentClasses() as well without success.

Any idea about what I'm loosing in the way?

**UPDATE**

Testing the code nicely implemented by Ian and shared here: https://gist.github.com/4065533, it works fine. But changing

```
OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF );
```

by

```
OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC );
```

it stops working. It seems that Pellet doesn't recognize the restrictions as super-clases of the class.

Comment: Is line 9 missing in your code example? It's referenced but not present. Also, it would increase readability if you format your code as code, by indenting it by four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of such problems is that the URI's don't match *exactly*. If you had included a fragment of your actual data, as Turtle or RDF XML, and if you had stated what the value of `NS` was, that could be ruled in or out definitively.

Generally speaking, posting a screengrab of the user interface of your editing tool is not nearly as useful to people who want to help you as posting the source itself.

**Update**

Well, it works for me. I've put my (hint: runnable) code in a gist [`https://gist.github.com/4065533`](https://gist.github.com/4065533). The only differences I can spot between my code and yours are the `OWL_FILE_NAME` var (presumably you have checked that you are loading the right input source?), and the use of Pellet which I don't have available at the moment. You could check that the source of the problem is not Pellet by swapping to the Jena rule reasoner, but I strongly doubt that Pellet will be a factor.

Please try my gist code and see if that helps illuminate the problem. If you still can't get your code working, please post a runnable minimal test case. It should be runnable without having to guess or fill-in any missing information.

Comment: Hi Ian. I've edited my answer addind and snippet of the owl generated code. I've explained too why I think the problem it's not caused by the Namespace. Thank so much for your advice.

Comment: For completeness, please state what value you are assigning to the `NS` variable (or constant). Also, thanks for including the OWL fragment but you don't include the namespace for that either.

Comment: Done! Namespace and NS variable stated.

Comment: I've tested your code and it works perfectly. Infact, I've changed Pellet by the same Jena rule reasoner as you and it works as well. When I execute my code with the Pellet reasoner I get some Advices in the console output. I've copied it [here](https://gist.github.com/4065779).
 
I was looking for their meaning, but I didn't find the cause and, since the remaining code works well, I haven't taken it so seriously.

Comment: As I supposed, that message is not relevant. I've edited the answer with new finds.